# Can I get the user id from Instagram image url?

Tags: api, instagram

For example from this url with the Instagram Api system.
https://instagram.fbud5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/ce6c07ce1504fb1456845f06d3742a52/5DE0ACE1/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/26863824_151784788815045_6841765216129122304_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbud5-1.fna.fbcdn.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user ID is not part of this URL.